# Weird delayed_job behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have a job (scheduled by `delayed_job`) that sends an email when a new user registers to the application. This is the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :country, :phone_number, :opt_in

  def email=(email)
    super
    Delayed::Job.enqueue self
  end

  def perform
    begin
      UserMailer.welcome_email self
    rescue => e
      STDERR.puts "Cannot perform the mailer: #{e}"
    end
  end
end
```

The action responsible for registering a new user is:

```
def  create
   user = User.new({:email => params[:email], 
                      :password => params[:password], 
                      :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation],
                      :country => params[:country],
                      :opt_in => Boolean(params[:opt_in]),
                      :phone_number => params[:phone_number]})

      if user.save(:validate => false)
        redirect_to wrap_users_path
      end 
end
```

When a user registers I get the following log:

> Started POST "/wrap_users" for
>   ... at 2011-05-30 12:58:35 +0200   Processing by WrapUsersController#create as HTML
>
> Parameters:
>   {"email"=>"xxxx",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "phone_number"=>"xxx",
>   "opt_in"=>"true", "country"=>"France"}
>
> AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO
>   "delayed_jobs" ("priority",
>   "attempts", "handler", "last_error",
>   "run_at", "locked_at", "failed_at",
>   "locked_by", "created_at",
>   "updated_at") VALUES (0, 0, '---
>   !ruby/ActiveRecord:User  attributes:
>   email: xxxx 
>   encrypted_password:
>   $2a$10$DwHB/5zSp38xdAAIkYriSuwIiLyKy2geU5kLmzjz2f1WsAuxpqyIW
>   reset_password_token:
>   reset_password_sent_at:
>   remember_created_at:   sign_in_count:
>   0  current_sign_in_at:
>   last_sign_in_at:   current_sign_in_ip:
>   last_sign_in_ip:   created_at:
>   updated_at:   country: France  opt_in:
>   true  phone_number: xxx ',
>   NULL, '2011-05-30 10:58:35.250464',
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-05-30
>   10:58:35.250560', '2011-05-30
>   10:58:35.250560')   AREL (2.1ms)
>
> INSERT INTO "users" ("email",
>   "encrypted_password",
>   "reset_password_token",
>   "reset_password_sent_at",
>   "remember_created_at",
>   "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at",
>   "last_sign_in_at",
>   "current_sign_in_ip",
>   "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at",
>   "updated_at", "country", "opt_in",
>   "phone_number") VALUES
>   ('xxx',
>   '$2a$10$DwHB/5zSp38xdAAIkYriSuwIiLyKy2geU5kLmzjz2f1WsAuxpqyIW',
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, '2011-05-30 10:58:35.251788',
>   '2011-05-30 10:58:35.251788',
>   'France', 't', 'xxx')
>   Redirected to
>   http://...:3000/wrap_users
>   Completed 302 Found in 277ms

As you can see, according to the Log an entry is being recorded to the `Delayed::Job` table. But in fact, when counting the number for records in this table (on `rails console` in the same development mode) I get 0.

What is going on? The log didn't mention any issue regarding the `insert into delayed_jobs` step.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table is empty probably because a worker took the job out of there and deleted it.
As a side note, I would use after_create callback instead of email= for scheduling a job. At least for one reason - even if the validation fails, you'll send the email anyway.

Comment: Well that's why it's weird. The worker that I am running, didn't process the job! So there is no reason why the job could be deleted.

Comment: I still highly recommend to use callbacks or observers approach instead of overriding setter.

Comment: Indeed. I changed it, I'm using after_create now! :)